How can software save tkinter Canvas Rectangle geometry when the root window is closed?
My program displays a Rectangle on top of a video image on a tkinter.Canvas. A mouse handler lets the user move and stretch the rectangle to identify an area of the video for processing. When the window is closed, the software should save the rectangle's geometry so it can restore it to the same place when the window is opened again. I thought a Destroy event handler bound to the root window could do that but it can't get the rectangle's coordinates.
Some stripped down code to illustrate the problem follows. I put the print statements in a function called from both the event handler and a Button in order to prove to myself the print statements worked as expected. The trial_count just helps read the results. It's not necessary to illustrate the problem.
import tkinter as tk

trial_count = 0
def print_data(caller):
    global trial_count
    trial_count += 1
    print('---------- trial ' + str(trial_count) + ' called from ' + caller + ' ------------')
    print('try canvas.winfo_width()', canvas.winfo_width())
    print('try canvas.coords(box)', canvas.coords(box))

def destroy_root(event):
    print_data('destroy_root')

def btn():
    print_data('button')

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Destroy>', destroy_root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
box = canvas.create_rectangle(20, 20, 100, 50)
tk.Button(root, text='click to print', command=btn).pack()
root.mainloop()


The result from running the script follows.

Trial 1 shows the results when the button is clicked. Canvas.winfo_width() and canvas.coords(box) both do what I expected.
Trial 2 shows the results the first time destroy_root was triggered when I closed the window.
canvas.winfo_width() succeeds so the Canvas hasn't been destroyed yet but then canvas.coords(box) fails. I don't understand why the code can't get the box's coords if the Canvas is still there?
I guess Trials 3 and 4 mean the  event was triggered again and again. I have no idea why?

---------- trial 1 called from button ------------
try canvas.winfo_width() 290
try canvas.coords(box) [20.0, 20.0, 100.0, 50.0]
---------- trial 2 called from destroy_root ------------
try canvas.winfo_width() 290
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/stephenvandellen/PycharmProjects/Windows/destroy.py", line 12, in destroy_root
    print_data('destroy_root')
  File "/Users/stephenvandellen/PycharmProjects/Windows/destroy.py", line 9, in print_data
    print('try canvas.coords(box)', canvas.coords(box))
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2823, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
---------- trial 3 called from destroy_root ------------
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/stephenvandellen/PycharmProjects/Windows/destroy.py", line 12, in destroy_root
    print_data('destroy_root')
  File "/Users/stephenvandellen/PycharmProjects/Windows/destroy.py", line 8, in print_data
    print('try canvas.winfo_width()', canvas.winfo_width())
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1354, in winfo_width
    self.tk.call('winfo', 'width', self._w))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!canvas"
---------- trial 4 called from destroy_root ------------
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/stephenvandellen/PycharmProjects/Windows/destroy.py", line 12, in destroy_root
    print_data('destroy_root')
  File "/Users/stephenvandellen/PycharmProjects/Windows/destroy.py", line 8, in print_data
    print('try canvas.winfo_width()', canvas.winfo_width())
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1354, in winfo_width
    self.tk.call('winfo', 'width', self._w))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!canvas"


I commonly see the global keyword used with tkinter modules. it immediately raises a red flag for poorly passed variables...  it is good practice to use classes and functions to have proper control over the flow of the code.

From the documentation: When the Destroy event is delivered to a widget, it is in a “half-dead” state: the widget still exists, but operations that involve it may return invalid results, or return an error. What I think this means is that some functions may work, but might return wrong results, while other functions will not work at all.

The destroy widget means that the canvas.winfo_width() does not exist because it has been destroyed. So it will throw an error for this reason.

OK, I see the Destroy event won't work. I did some more searching and discovered root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", handler). I tried it out and looks like the handler function can do exactly what I need. I haven't posted much in stackoverflow. Should I add that information as an Answer to close the issue?

Okay, so it was a good attempt.
I have re-organised the code and made some modifications.

wrapped the code in a class
i had to replace the bind method with protocol

basically, in summary, the canvas.winfo_width() does not exist once destroyed. Hence, the error is thrown.
When the self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy_root) is introduced, it works. see the code:
import tkinter as tk


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.trial_count = 0
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy_root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.box = self.canvas.create_rectangle(20, 20, 100, 50)
        tk.Button(self.root, text='click to print', command=self.btn).pack()

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def print_data(self, caller):
        self.trial_count += 1
        print('---------- trial ' + str(self.trial_count) + ' called from ' + caller + ' ------------')

        print('try canvas.winfo_width()', self.canvas.winfo_width())
        print('try canvas.coords(box)', self.canvas.coords(self.box))
            
    def destroy_root(self):
        try:
            # Get the location of the canvas relative to its parent
            x = self.canvas.winfo_rootx()
            y = self.canvas.winfo_rooty()
            print(f"Canvas location - x: {x}, y: {y}")
        except:
            print('didnt work...')
        # now destroy
        self.root.destroy()

    def btn(self):
        self.print_data('button')


bit = App()
bit.mainloop()

which now returns this:
---------- trial 1 called from button ------------
try canvas.winfo_width() 382
try canvas.coords(box) [20.0, 20.0, 100.0, 50.0]
---------- trial 2 called from button ------------
try canvas.winfo_width() 382
try canvas.coords(box) [20.0, 20.0, 100.0, 50.0]
---------- trial 3 called from button ------------
try canvas.winfo_width() 382
try canvas.coords(box) [20.0, 20.0, 100.0, 50.0]
Canvas location - x: 1856, y: 205


OP said when closing the window, canvas.winfo_width() works but canvas.coords() does not.  You can see that in the output for trial 2 in the question.

good point, but same or similar rationalle resolves the error.

@VanDee,  i trust it works for you.  More importantly, you also have better formed code. If you are using global this is probably a hint that you are ready to move to class :-)
